# How to hide already existing header bar from TabBar react-native

Tags: react-native

**Hii I have TabBar name Home and Setting having headerbar and in Home Tab there is a button to go to Details class and i want to hide headerbar when i am in details class**

[image]

**When i press Go To Tabs button Details class is open in which again headerbar of tabbar is showing and i want to hide it**

**Code for calling TabBar**

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
    First: {screen: First},
  TopTabs: {screen: TopTabs}
},
{initialRouteName: 'First'}
```

);

**Code for TabBar**

```
const HomeRoot = createStackNavigator({   
Home: {
  screen: Home,
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
  }, 
},    
Details: {
  screen: Details,
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
   }, 
  },
},{
initialRouteName: 'Home'});
```

**Code for Two Tabs Home and Settings**

```
  const RootStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
     Home: {
      screen: HomeRoot,
      navigationOptions : {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon:  <Image source={{uri: 
      'https://png.icons8.com/Home/ultraviolet/50/3498db'}} style= . 
      {{width:20, height: 20}}/>
     },
    },
    Settings: {
     screen: Settings,
     navigationOptions : {
      tabBarLabel: 'Setting',
      tabBarIcon:  <Image source={{uri: 
      'https://png.icons8.com/Home/ultraviolet/50/3498db'}} style= . 
      {{width:20, height: 20}}/>
     },     
   },
 },
```

**code for TopTabs**

```
export default class TopTabs extends React.Component {  
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   return {
     title: navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'A Nested 
       DetailsScreen'),
    };
  }; 

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);  
 }     
 render() {  
   const { navigation } = this.props;
   const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default 
   value');
   return (
      <AppScreen/>
   );
    } 
   }
```

Comment: edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Add navigation options:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerMode: 'none'
}
```

or another solution:

```
static navigationOptions = { header: null }

const HomeRoot = createStackNavigator({   
Home: {
  screen: Home, 
},    
Details: {
  screen: Details,
},{
headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
initialRouteName: 'Home'});
```

Comment: Please update your post along with code. In have also updated my answer please check